# How can I select lines in reason of a value in awk?

Tags: bash, awk, fileparsing

Let's assume I have a file which structure looks like this:

```
AAAA 700 something1 something_else1
AAAA 98 something2 something_else2
AAAA 2000 something3 something_else3
BBBB 200 something4 something_else4
BBBB 21 something5 something_else5
BBBB 300 something6 something_else6
```

I need to extract, for each value in column $1, the whole line having the highest value in column $1. This means that, for the field AAAA, I would need to print the line in which $2=2000. The output should thus look like:

```
AAAA 2000 something3 something_else3
BBBB 300 something6 something_else6
```

I did it with python, but the file is huge and the process is very time-consuming. Is there any way to do it with awk?

Comment: Did you mean to say `having the highest value in column $2` instead of `...in column $1`?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1!=prev { if (rec!="") print rec; max=$2; rec=$0 }
$2 > max { max=$2; rec=$0 }
{ prev=$1 }
END { if (rec!="") print rec }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
AAAA 2000 something3 something_else3
BBBB 300 something6 something_else6
```

The above assumes the `$1` values are always grouped together as shown in your sample input. Given that, it only stores 1 record in memory at a time (since you say your input file is huge that could be important), prints the records in the same order they were read, will work even for zero or negative `$2` values, and will not output anything for an empty input file.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
awk '
!($1 in max) || ($2>max[$1]) {
  max[$1]=$2; a[$1]=$0;
} 
END{ 
  for(i in a){ 
    print a[i];
  }
}' input_file
```

you get (the order may be different because it depends on hash in `a`):

```
BBBB 300 something6 something_else6
AAAA 2000 something3 something_else3
```

Comment: Change `$2>max[$1]` to `!($1 in max) || ($2>max[$1])` so `max[$1]` and `a[$1]` are always populated the first time a new `$1` value is seen. You could also make it more awk-ish by moving the condition outside of the action part and into the condition part instead of adding an `if (...)` around it inside the action part.

Comment: @EdMorton I understand, thanks a lot for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

a combination of sort/awk will be easiest

```
$ sort -k1,2nr file | awk '!a[$1]++'

AAAA 2000 something3 something_else3
BBBB 300 something6 something_else6
```

sort by first field and second field (descending), let awk pick the first rows of the groups (highest by design).